# Filtering List based on a nested list using LINQ

Tags: linq

Let's say we have a List of Projects and this list contains another list of Users.

How can I construct a LINQ query that let's say get me all the projects of a specific user based on his UserID?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a very basic question. I suggest you read a LINQ tutorial because you learn almost nothing by reading the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Lets try something like this:

```
Projects.Where(pr => pr.Users.Any(us => us.ID == uid) )
```

I suggest to You read [LINQ tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) or [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq) as well